# Intellij Cannot Find JVM SDK to run Scala Worksheet

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

How can the following error be resolved, such that Scala Worksheets run IntelliJ IDEA?

`Worksheet configuration error:: Cannot find jdk null for compile server, underlying message: No JVM SDK configured`

I have a JDK SDK configured under "Project Settings" -> "Project" -> "Project SDK" and I see it the SDK listed under "Platform Settings" -> "SDKs".

I also have "Languages & Frameworks" -> "Scala Compile Server" -> "Use external compile server for scala" unchecked, which is the default.

Software Versions:

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2016.13
- JDK 1.8

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable "Languages & Frameworks" -> "Scala Compile Server" -> "Use external compile server for scala".
2. Under "Languages & Frameworks" -> "Scala Compile Server" -> "Use external compile server for scala" -> "JVM SDK", select your JVM SDK version.
3. Disable "Languages & Frameworks" -> "Scala Compile Server" -> "Use external compile server for scala".

[shrug]